# Compare 2 result sets

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  I have 2 queries.  The first one is:

```
SELECT
col1,
col2
FROM tableA
```

A typical result set of this query is:

col1    col2

facilityA   10

facilityB   20

The second one is:

```
SELECT
colx,
COUNT(*) AS 'Totals'
FROM tableB
GROUP BY colx
```

A typical result set of this query is:

colx    Totals

facilityA   10

facilityB   50

I want to return all records in the first result set where the values are different between col2 and Totals from the second result set, for corresponding values between col1 and colx.  For instance, the given example should return:

col1    col2

facilityB  20

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use the [EXCEPT clause](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/07/sql-server-except-clause-in-sql-server-is-similar-to-minus-clause-in-oracle/).  This will compare each row column by column and if an identical row exists between the two datasets it will be excluded:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM tableA

EXCEPT

SELECT colx, COUNT(*) AS 'Totals'
FROM tableB
GROUP BY colx
```